# Power Bi Embed Token and Error PowerBIEntityNotFound

Tags: c#, azure, powerbi-embedded

I have power bi pro and azure ad-free with clientid and clientid secret 
with allow using power bi API

I'm the only admin user.

I can get the first token from azure >> works well in code for the power bi embed token I getting error

> PowerBIEntityNotFound

c# code API >> `client.SendAsync(..paramter azure token ..)`

for the bode, parameters >> sending JSON with reportId and Dataset

Comment: Did you followed the official tutorials? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/power-bi-embedded/

Answer (score 3):

This error usually happens when:
- The account that requested Azure authentication has no workspace (or report) permission sent as a parameter;
- Actually the workspace or report identifiers do not belong to your domain.

Try checking the parameters you are using for workspace and reporting by accessing [PowerBi Online](https://app.powerbi.com/home), if they are correct the problem is account permission.

Comment: I had this issue when the report was in one workspace, but the underlying data model was in another and the service principal had only been given access to the report's workspace.